# powershell start program on remote machine, webservice interface not working

Tags: web-services, wcf, powershell

I have a remote server where I have a program (C#, WCF) with a webservice interface that I need to start from another machine. Currently I have a powershell script on the remote machine with:

```
 Start-Process -WindowStyle Minimized 'path to exe'
```

This works if I start the script on the server directly with the following in a cmd prompt.

```
 Powershell.exe start.ps1
```

Webservice interface is fully functional.

However when I run the script remotely through powershell with

`Invoke-WmiMethod –class Win32_process -name Create -ArgumentList "powershell.exe c:\Start.ps1" -ComputerName $serverName -credential $Cred`

The program starts up on the remote machine, but webservice interface isn't working ? I have tried to look at the wsdl but it doesn't show.

Is there any special permissions or something that needs to be added when calling the script from remotely to get it to work ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, your problems lies in starting the exe on a remote server. If you're using WIN2012 R2 (or higher) Powershell remoting should be activated per default (if you're using an older WIN version perform some Google queries about how to activate Powershell remoting).

Via Powershell remoting you can use `Invoke-Command` to start the exe on the remote. Example:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 1.2.3.4 -Credential (Get-Credential) -Scriptblock { Start-Process "your.exe" }
```

Using Powershell remoting has some advantages.

- Standardized mechanism usage via `WSMAN`.
- Remoting uses HTTP(S) for transport. Therefore working with firewalls becomes easier.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Problem is not starting, that works. But when it is started the webservice isn't working, meaning I cannot see the WSDL for the program. If running the same script on the server that starts the program, the webservice is running correct.